# How to add mute/unmute button to browser audio player?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, audio-player

So I have my code here, and it works great. Only thing is there are no mute/unmute buttons and I have no idea how to add them.

```
<audio src="MUSIC URL" autoplay loop>
    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element </p>
</audio>
```

Comment: Add `controls` attribute to `audio` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this, get a play and pause button .png and use them. Then make a folder called audio and put the files in there for you music. I put the play and pause in a folder called images.

```html
<style type="text/css">
audio {visibility: hidden; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; top: -300px; left: -300px;}
#pauseplay {float: right; width: 48px; height: 48px; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer}
</style>

<audio controls loop>
<source src="**your website url here**/audio/waves.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="**your website url here**/audio/waves.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<img id="pauseplay" src="**your website url here**/images/play.png" alt="button" title="Play/Pause">
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
 var playing = !!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) || !!window.ontouchstart || (!!window.Touch && !!window.Touch.length) || !!window.onmsgesturechange || (window.DocumentTouch && window.document instanceof window.DocumentTouch),
 snd = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0],
 ctrl = document.getElementById('pauseplay');
 playing = !playing;
 ctrl.title = playing? 'Pause' : 'Play';
 if(playing){snd.autoplay = false; ctrl.src = '**your website url** here/images/pause.png';}
 ctrl.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(playing){
   snd.pause();
  } else {
   snd.play();
  }
  playing = !playing;
  ctrl.title = playing? 'Pause' : 'Play';
  ctrl.src = playing? '**your website url here**/images/pause.png' : '**your website url here**/images/play.png';
 }, false);
})();
</script>
```

If you want to see it live l[ook at this site](http://hamptonsunrise.com/) I made.

Comment: your welcome, I have float: right; for the images because that's where I wanted them, but you can change that

Comment: How do you enable autoplay? I changed {snd.autoplay = false; to true but no dice..

Comment: if(playing){snd.autoplay = true;

Comment: I did that but it's not working, even when it says true it's the same as if it was false..

Comment: Wow, look on my HamptonSunrise.com website again and view the source and make sure you have yours the same way

Comment: You're site doesn't autoplay either? And they are the same.

Comment: What are you looking at my site on? autoplay doesn't work on IOS mobile, and I'm not sure about Android because I dont have one

Comment: I'm using Chrome.

Comment: on a computer, laptop or Apple device? oh yeah Chrome doesn't autoplay, it's the website engine

Comment: check on another web browser to see it then

Comment: do you have Adblock?

Comment: No.. It's ok, I'll just leave it how it is. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: look at what is and what is not supported formats currently https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: Could this be the problem?  I didn't upload a Ogg file, just the mp3?

Comment: I always upload both because some browsers and devices don't support one or the other. You can convert the mp3 to ogg and save it too. free  sites to do it are http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg  http://online-audio-converter.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should add `controls` attribute to [`audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) tag.

> If this attribute is present, the browser will offer controls to allow the user to control audio playback, including volume, seeking, and pause/resume playback. 
>   [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

```html
<audio src="http://audiomicro-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/preview/1030/caca5b5fcde48f9" controls>
  <p>Your browser does not support the audio element </p>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play();">Sound on</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].pause();">Sound off</button>
<audio autoplay preload="auto" loop src="your.mp3"></audio>
```

It is set on autoplay and loop, you can pause and resume by clicking the buttons. The best way to avoid diplaying the unsuitable browser player.